# Output and directory structure in typescript

Tags: typescript

Let say that have have the given directory structure for my project :

```
project 
| app
  | dist
  | src
    | components
      | some .ts files
    | services
      | some .ts files
    | some ts files
```

I want to have in dist the output of typescript compilation, but with the same structure starting from app. Example of what I want after compiling

```
project 
| app
  | dist
      components
      | some .js files
    | services
      | some .js files
    | some js files
  | src
    | components
      | some .ts files
    | services
      | some .ts files
    | some ts files
```

But I tried every possible solution I could think of with compile options, my result for dist folder is always that one :

```
project 
| app
  | dist
    | app 
      | src
        | components
          | some .js files
        | services
          | some .js files
        | some js files
```

My tsconfig.json file :

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "lib": [ "es2015", "dom" ],
    "noImplicitAny": true,
    "suppressImplicitAnyIndexErrors": true,
    "outDir": "app/lib"
  },
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules/*"
  ]
}
```

I tried a lot of solutions like playing with outDir, putting my tsconfig in app/src and run compilation from there... Nothing, just can't figure this out.

Answer (score 7):

Give `"rootDir": "./src"` in compilerOptions

Answer (score 1):

This is the `tsconfig.json` for one of my projects that does exactly what you want: (replace `build` with `dist`)

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "target": "ES6",
        "module": "commonjs",
        "noEmitOnError": true,
        "noImplicitAny": true,
        "experimentalDecorators": true,
        "sourceMap": true,
        "sourceRoot": "src",
        "outDir": "build"
    },
    "exclude": [
        "build",
        "node_modules"
    ]
}
```

Comment: Yeah, I tried that, thinking it would work. But copying your tsconfig, I still have my files in dist/src/my-files. My version of tsc is 2.0.10. Any throughs why ?

Answer (score 1):

As Nikhil Yeole said use

```
 "rootDir": {
              "description": "Specifies the root directory of input files. Use to control the output directory structure with --outDir.",
              "type": "string"
            }
```

for a full list of the properties see here:
https://github.com/SchemaStore/schemastore/blob/master/src/schemas/json/tsconfig.json

:)